# How to plot function of multiple variables in R by initializing all variables but one

Tags: r, plot

What's the easiest way to plot a function of multiple variables in a **2D graph** by giving some of the input parameters a value. Let's consider a simple example

`my.function<-function(a,b,x){a*x^2+b}`

Now I want to plot the simple parabola where `a=1` an `b=0` . So I define a new function:
`new.function<-function(x){my.function(1,0,x)};
plot(new.function)`
.

Is there any way where I can plot the function without defining `new.function`?

Normally I use Mathematica and in Mathematica it would be:

`Plot[my.function[1,0,x],{x ... }]`

Comment: Basically the same in R   `plot(function(x) { my.function(1,0,x) })`

Comment: Or you can use `curve` like `curve(my.function(1, 0, x), from=0, to=10)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers, I am sharing @G5W 's comment as answer in here:

`plot(function(x) { my.function(1,0,x) })`

I believe this is the best way of those provided in here

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to define a new function. You can use the original function, `my.function`, and pass in x-values 1 through 10 to plot the parabola:

```
my.function <- function(a,b,x){a*x^2+b}
x <- 1:10
y <- my.function(a=1,b=0,x=x)
plot(y~x)
```

Comment: The function is vectorized, so no need for `sapply`. `y <- my.function(a = 1, b = 0, x = 1:10)` works fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my post. It's much more simple without `sapply()`.